# How to add to dist object

Tags: r, addition, distance

The sample codes are like the following, and I want to create a new object `d3=(d1+d2)/2`, but you know items of `d1` are not the same with those of `d2`, so directly using add is impossible. What's the way?

```
library(recommenderlab)
data(MSWeb)
d1 = dissimilarity(MSWeb[1:5,], method = "jaccard")
d2 = dissimilarity(MSWeb[2:6,], method = "jaccard")
```

Answer (score 1):

So i'm assuming you want to match up dimnames between the distance matrices prior to doing arithmetic . As far as I know there is no easy way to do that with regular matrices which means having it work for distance matrices is even less likely. One strategy would be to expand the distance matrix values with the names, do the merging and aggretaing, then convert back to a distance matrix. I've created some helper functions to make this easier. First, here's a way to convert the diagonal distance matrix to paired distances in a data.frame

```
as.data.frame.dist<-function(x) {
    stopifnot(is(x, "dist"))
    s <- attr(x, "Size")
    n <- attr(x, "Labels")
    data.frame(
      id1 = unlist(sapply(1:(length(n)-1), function(i) n[1:i])),
      id2 = rep(n[-1], 1:(length(n)-1)),
      dist = as.numeric(x)
    )
}
```

For example, if we run

```
as.data.frame(d1)

#    id1 id2      dist
# 1    1   2 0.7500000
# 2    1   3 0.8000000
# 3    2   3 1.0000000
# 4    1   4 1.0000000
# 5    2   4 0.3333333
# 6    3   4 1.0000000
# 7    1   5 1.0000000
# 8    2   5 1.0000000
# 9    3   5 1.0000000
# 10   4   5 1.0000000
```

We get all the pairwise comparisons expanded into rows with IDs values that we can match up to other potentially non-matching sets. It seems like you just want to take the average distance for each set of points, so you could do something like this

```
dd <- rbind(as.data.frame(d1), as.data.frame(d2))
dd <- aggregate(dist~id1+id2, dd, mean)
```

Now, it we want to turn this data.frame back into a distance object, we'll need to write another helper function. Here is once such function

```
df2dist<-function(x, ids=1:2, vals=3, lvls=NULL) {
    if(is.null(lvls)) {
        lvls <- sort(unique(c(as.character(x[,ids[1]]), as.character(x[,ids[2]]))))
    }
    i <- as.numeric(factor(x[,ids[1]], levels=lvls))
    j <- as.numeric(factor(x[,ids[2]], levels=lvls))
    stopifnot(all(i<j))
    n <- length(lvls)
    idx <- n*(i-1) - i*(i-1)/2 + j-i
    r <- rep(NA, n*(n-1)/2)
    r[idx] <- x[,vals]
    structure(r, class="dist", Labels=lvls, Size=n, Diag=FALSE, Upper=FALSE)
}
```

Where we expect a three column data.frame that has pairs of values and the distance between them. We can use this on our sample to get

```
df2dist(dd)

#           1         2         3         4         5
# 2 0.7500000                                        
# 3 0.8000000 0.6666667                              
# 4 1.0000000 0.6666667 1.0000000                    
# 5 1.0000000 0.8333333 1.0000000 1.0000000          
# 6        NA 0.3333333 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

So there is a bit of work to transform the objects to match on labels, but it is pretty straight forward.

Comment: I'v tested the codes, as the default distance matrix is a lower triangular matrix, perhaps in the function as.data.frame.dist, d1 and d2 should be edited like these:  id1 = unlist(sapply(1:(length(n)-1), function(i) rep(n[i],length(n)-i)));
      id2 = unlist(sapply(2:length(n), function(i) n[i:length(n)])),